# How do I enable DEBUG logging just for slow queries?

Tags: cassandra

The debugging level is set at INFO, I want to enable logging of slow running queries for which slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms is set. If debugging level will be set to DEBUG, it will log queries running longer than slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms but at the same time lot of other debugging info will be logged.
I do not want any debug info other than slow running query, is it possible to only enable logging of slow running queries and nothing else at debug level?

```
[cassandra@localhost ~]$ nodetool getlogginglevels
Logger Name                                        Log Level
...
org.apache.cassandra                                    INFO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug logging is enabled by default since Cassandra 2.2 and goes to `debug.log`. This is to reduce the "noise" that goes into `system.log`.

It is possible to disable debug logging by removing the appender in `conf/logback.xml` but it is *not recommended*. Debug logs are crucial if you are investigating an issue or need to understand what is going on with your system so it's recommended to always have it on.

If you want to go against best practice, disable debug logging and set the logging level for the class `org.apache.cassandra.db.monitoring` to `DEBUG`. Note that this isn't persistent and you will need to set it every time Cassandra is restarted. Cheers!

Comment: Erick, please see the steps followed below, set db.monitoring to debug and disabled debug as whole - but dont see slow queries being written to debug. The slow query threshold is set to 5ms # nodetool getlogginglevels
Logger Name Log Level
ROOT  INFO
org.apache.cassandra DEBUG

# nodetool setlogginglevel org.apache.cassandra OFF
# nodetool setlogginglevel org.apache.cassandra.db.monitoring DEBUG

root@9bbcf53ae43a:/var/log/cassandra# nodetool getlogginglevels
Logger Name Log Level
ROOT INFO
org.apache.cassandra OFF
org.apache.cassandra.db.monitoring DEBUG